# Calculate a 30-60-90 day report with expiration date - 6 months

Tags: t-sql, sap-ase

I am trying to calculate a 30-60-90 day aging report based upon a date field (using t-sql)

Here is the logic...
I have an item that has a expiration date of 6/10/2019
I need to calculate that date - 6 months and then take that value and calculate if it falls into 30, 60 or 90 days

Here is the current code I have:

```
 SELECT distinct(T0.distnumber) as 'Batch Number', 
 T0.itemcode, 
 T1.itemname, 
 T0.Indate as 'Admission Date', 
 CASE WHEN Datediff(day, T0.indate,GETDATE()) <=30 THEN T0.distnumber 
 END'<30Days',
 CASE WHEN DateDiff(day,T0.indate,GETDATE()) >= 30 AND 
 DateDiff(day,T0.indate,GETDATE()) < 60 THEN T0.distnumber END '30 to 60 
 Days',
 CASE WHEN DateDiff(day, T0.indate,GETDATE()) >= 60  AND 
 DateDiff(day,T0.indate,GETDATE()) < 90 THEN T0.distnumber END '60 to 90 
 Days',
 CASE WHEN Datediff(day, T0.indate,GETDATE()) >90 THEN T0.distnumber 
 END'>90Days'

 From OBTN T0
 left join OITM T1 on T0.itemcode = T1.itemcode
```

Comment: This looks like a great start, what is the issue you are having with your code? Btw, I helped you with `CASE` statements yesterday, glad to see you're attempting to implement them! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! :) The issue I am having is that we actually need to take the indate field, calculate the date 6 months from now and then age it. so right now i'm having an issue with taking the indate and calculating 6 months ago. I can calculate the difference in days however I cannot get it into date form.

Comment: Here is the line of code I am struggling with.... I want to take the result of this line ( it is # of days) and have it show the date:

Comment: DATEDIFF(day, T0.Expdate, DATEADD(month, -6, T0.Expdate)) as 'Exp Date - 
      6 Mo',